# Deploy app, C++, Visual Studio 2015 community version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a C++ app for use on multiple systems. I've already gotten everything to work in the release configuration. Now since i don't have any experience with deploys at all, i'd like to ask - what's the simplest way to deploy it from Visual Studio 2015 community, so that it could be installed as a portable app on flash drives and similar?
I've checked out google, but with no luck so far all of the solutions i checked require some sort of additional software that is only available for the pro version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible answer would be: compile without dependency on VC++ runtime libraries (select this in the project properties ->  C++ -> code generation) and choose the oldest Windows version it should run on (in project properties -> general). Maybe even select Windows XP compatibility.

This should be enough, unless your program depends on other libraries or optional Windows features that may be not present.

And test a lot :)

-- dd

Comment: thanks for the idea! but for whatever reason it will not let me set compatibility below 8.1.

Comment: This is in General-> Platform toolset. For XP, select "Visual studio 2015 -  Windows XP (v140_xp)"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to your project's `Properties` (right click on your project) then under `C/C++` and `Code Generation` switch your `Runtime Library` from `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` to `Multi-threaded (/MT)`.

This way your dependencies to the runtime library will be statically linked and not require you to have any of them installed at the target system.

Comment: thanks, I've already set it to MT when tinkering with the release. didn't think that would basically be everything it needed!